# How can I mark rows where the fee charged per transaction type ID per trade date per account ID does not equal 2.25?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So i have a file of transaction data that needs to be assessed for incorrect charging; "correct charging" means that each trade gets charged $2.25, but only when the trade is unique to the transaction type ID, the trade date, actual and order quantities, and the account ID.
[image]

I tried exploring named ranges and sumifs but didn't really get the desired result. Ideally, it would be best as a function in the "Concern?" column cells that could be copy pasted down, but I'm open to other types of solutions. Really, I just need to make sure I can know if there is a correctly charged trade in the pool of incorrectly charged trades unique to the day and the transaction type ID.

Comment: Please use markdown table to post data as data. https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables. Please share expected results with given sample.

Comment: What was your try with SUMIF(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Sumproduct` to sum up fee charges for identical rows:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT($AJ$2:$AJ$7*($E$2:$E$7=E2)*($G$2:$G$7=G2)*($P$2:$P$7=P2)*($Z$2:$Z$7=Z2)*($AA$2:$AA$7=AA2))=2.25,"No","Yes")
```

[image]

UPDATE:
If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula to check for a range:

```vb
=LET(minValue,2.21, maxValue,2.28,
result,SUMPRODUCT($AJ$2:$AJ$7*($E$2:$E$7=E2)*($G$2:$G$7=G2)*($P$2:$P$7=P2)*($Z$2:$Z$7=Z2)*($AA$2:$AA$7=AA2)),
IF(AND(result>=minValue,result<=maxValue),"no","yes"))
```

It's the same `SUMPRODUCT`-formula as above - but checked against min- and maxValue.

Comment: this seems to work perfectly for my use! Would you have any idea how to tweak it a little to basically give some room for error 2.25? Like maybe allow for a sum between 2.21 and 2.28?

Comment: What is your Excel version?

Comment: it's microsoft 365 excel!

Comment: Thank you so much! Wow I'm amazed at how you can leverage whatever LET() is into a sort of programmatic solution, I've never seen that before. How'd you learn to be able to do solve things like that?

Comment: You can learn about LET [here](https://exceljet.net/functions/let-function#example1) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999#:~:text=Excel%20for%20Microsoft%20365%20Excel%20for%20Microsoft%20365,apply%20within%20the%20scope%20of%20the%20LET%20function)

Comment: thanks! Ill read up on it

Comment: also...say i wanted to figure out how i am owed, as in, in a perfect world where all the trades were charged correctly for 2.25. How could I figure out how much more I need to charge them for everything to be ok? This seems like a good brain tease